# How to implement ajax login in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have asp.net web site, for registered users.

In the login page, I use ajax call for authentication. the call can return url of home page, or other string of error.

code:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    data: "{'userName':'" + $("#txtUserName").val() + "'" + ",'password':'" + $("#txtPassword").val() + "','rememberMe':'" + $("#cbRemember").prop('checked') + "'}",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "Login.aspx/LoginSite",
    success: function (result) {
        if (/^Home.aspx/.test(result.d.url)) {
            location = result.d.url;
        }
        else {
            setMsg(result.d.success, result.d.msg, "loginMsg");
        }
    },
    error: function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
        setMsg(false, "שגיאה בלתי צפויה", "loginMsg");
    }
```

There is a  problem, that when user is in Login page, and 15 minutes of session passed, he has to refresh page. if he does not refresh, he get message of error, because there is no access to server.

So I change `EnableSessionState` to `False`.

But now I have another problem:

in the ajax call, after authentication the user, I want to insert his `Id` to session, but because of the `EnableSessionState="False"`, Session throws an exception.
what can I do? maybe there is another way to implement ajax login in asp.net?

Comment: So what you want if 15 minutes are passed in login page you want to refresh the page automatically ?

Comment: thanks for reply. can you show me how to do it in code? because I tried some ways to do it and it did not eork.

Comment: Do you want to do what i have said in comments ?

Comment: yes. if you have easy way to do it, I will use it.

Comment: Use settimeout method of javascript to check if 15 minutes have passed refresh the page.

Comment: setTimeout(function () { location.reload(); }, 60 * 1000 * 15);

Comment: thanks, I will try it.

Comment: You may be loosing session early in production enviornment that' why it may not be working